# QML modal dialog: qt.qpa.dialogs: Cannot run window modal dialog without parent window

Tags: qt, qml

I ran into the following problem: When the dialog 'testDialog' is opened, the following  error message is reported in the debug console off qt creator: qt.qpa.dialogs: Cannot run window modal dialog without parent window. How to solve this issue? I'm using on macOS 12.6 and Qt6.5.4.

main.cpp

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtQuick>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QQuickView View;
  View.resize(640, 480);
  View.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
  View.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/SimpleScreen.qml"));
  View.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

SimpleScreen.qml

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Dialogs

Item
{
  MessageDialog
  {
    id: testDialog
    title: "Test"
    text: "For test purposes"
  }

  Rectangle
  {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: parent.width / 2
    height: parent.height / 2
    color: "red"

    MouseArea
    {
      anchors.fill: parent

      onClicked:
      {
        testDialog.open()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `QQuickView` you can use a `QGuiApplication` and `QQmlApplicationEngine` which is what you get when you create a new Qt Quick Application project from with in QtCreator. This gives you the following `main.cpp` and `Main.qml`.

The `Main.qml` actually needs its own `Window` instead of `Item`. This `Window` will then automatically become the parent of the `MessageDialog`.

Your example on my Ubuntu machine with Qt 6.5.4 didn't even give any error message. The click on the `MouseArea` did nothing.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/untitled3/Main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(
        &engine,
        &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app,
        []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Dialogs

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    MessageDialog {
        id: testDialog
        title: "Test"
        text: "For test purposes"
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.height / 2
        color: "red"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: testDialog.open()
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can also solve it by forwarding a pointer to your `QQuickView` as a context property. But context properties are a bit magical for my taste and you can quickly lose track of where something is coming from and what is available.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtQuick>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("__window", &view);
    view.resize(640, 480);
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/untitled3/Main.qml"_qs);
    view.setSource(url);
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Dialogs

Item {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480

    MessageDialog {
        id: testDialog
        title: "Test"
        text: "For test purposes"
        parentWindow: __window // use context property
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.height / 2
        color: "red"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: testDialog.open()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit of explanation why and how to get it working even with `QQuickView` on this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67868454/qquickview-shows-an-empty-window-when-calling-show